# Create lookup field that can relate to two types of objects

Tags: custom-object, lookup, custom-field, related-list, relationships

I have a custom object, that I would like to relate to the built-in Accounts and Opportunities objects. Sometimes this custom object can be related to an Account, sometimes it can be related to an Opportunity.

I want to have a field on my custom object, that states what the record is related to. (So basically a "Related To" field, like the **Event** object already has.)

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create your own polymorphic lookups in Salesforce. You would need to create two separate lookup fields, one to Account and one to Opportunity.

You can then, if you wish, use formula fields to pull in data from whichever lookup is populated. However, you will not be able to achieve the same look and feel as the native Related To or Name polymorphic lookups.

Comment: Thank you David Reed for the really fast answer!

Comment: @Laureant related idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqzBAAS